# MySQL query to get best Ranks from one table and UPDATE with results another

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Ranking board for the best first 100 blogs for each gender Males and Females.

I have a blogs table:

```
PRIMARY
blogs_id  users_id  blogs_score  blogs_score_time      gender
    1         11        2852     2015-09-09 05:21:51     m <-- same score but older date
    2         23        2146     2015-09-10 07:31:54     m
    3         23        2146     2015-09-10 07:32:26     m
    4         23        2852     2015-09-10 04:42:15     m <-- same score but newer date
    5         51        1793     2015-09-11 08:15:55     f
    6         88        2947     2015-09-11 09:33:18     f
```

I have a users table:

```
PRIMARY
  id  best_rank  gender
  11      0         m
  23      0         m
  51      0         f
  88      0         f
```

I need to COUNT best ranks (using MAX(blogs_score) and MAX(blogs_score_time)) for each user from **Blogs table** and INSERT/UPDATE the **Users table** with the best ranks for the first 100 users of each gender with highest ranks, so the result should be:

```
PRIMARY
  id  best_rank  gender
  11      2         m
  23      1         m
  51      2         f
  88      1         f
```

Where user id 11 has best rank of 2 because user id 11 has same score with user 23 but older date than user 23. Where user 51 has rank 2 because of Female's group. I have added column `blogs_score_time` to prevent tie ranking. And the date 2015-09-10 means September 10.

*The final idea is to show the Rank position in user's profile and once someone voted (`blogs_score` changes in the blogs table), the `best_rank` column in the `users` table must be updated with the new ranks recalculation for **ALL** 100 users who has the best ranks in particular gender group.*

How to adapt and fix this (not working) query to my needs?

```
 $sql->query("UPDATE users
            JOIN (SELECT b.users_id,
                         @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank,
                         MAX(blogs_score), MAX(blogs_score_time)
                  FROM blogs b
                         JOIN (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
                  ORDER BY  b.blogs_score DESC, p.blogs_score_time DESC LIMIT 100
                 ) ranks ON (ranks.users_id = users.id)
            SET users.best_rank = ranks.rank");
```

Or how to adapt and fix this (not working) query

```
 $sql->query("INSERT INTO users (best_rank, id)
                  SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank, b.users_id
                       FROM blogs b
                       LEFT JOIN users u ON b.users_id = u.id
                  GROUP BY b.users_id, b.blogs_score, b.blogs_score_time, b.gender
                  ORDER BY b.blogs_score DESC, b.blogs_score_time DESC
              ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE best_rank = VALUES(rank)");
```

Please help me with the query to solve it. I didn't find any similar solution on stackoverflow and it seems very complicated for me to write such a query alone.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE users u, (
SELECT 
( 
    CASE gender 
    WHEN @curType 
    THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
    ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curType := gender END
) + 1 AS rank, users_id, blogs_score, blogs_score_time, gender 
FROM blogs, 
(SELECT @curRow := 0, @curType := '') r
ORDER BY gender, blogs_score DESC, blogs_score_time DESC
) r1
SET u.best_rank = r1.rank
WHERE
u.id = r1.users_id
```

It does 2 works:

1. inner select query generates rank as per gender, score and time
2. updates user table with respective rank.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the a `GROUP BY` clause this way before ORDER BY

```
$sql->query("UPDATE users
              JOIN (SELECT b.users_id,
                         @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank,
                         MAX(b.blogs_score), MAX(b.blogs_score_time   )
                  FROM blogs b
                         JOIN (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
                  GROUP BY b.user_id, rank
                  ORDER BY  b.blogs_score DESC, p.blogs_score_time DESC LIMIT 100
                 ) ranks ON (ranks.users_id = users.id)
            SET users.best_rank = ranks.rank");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this query I posted as a general idea how to count the rank and how approximately the UPDATE query should look like. Actually this query is not working as is. I think MAX(b.blogs_score), MAX(b.blogs_score_time) should not be in SELECT when applying curRank to b.users_id. I could be wrong but hope someone will help.